# azure app service plan difference between p2v2 and p1v3?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have a site running on azure P1v2 for a while and now it starts to struggle on CPU (assume it is more requests than other issues).
So I am looking at buying a better plan, at the moment, quite confused between p2v2 and p1v3.

P1V3 have 2vCU and bit more memory, but it is cheaper than P2V2, which also has 2 CPU. So why p2v2 is more expensive?

Also p1v3 has a minimal 195 ACU but p2v2 has 420 total ACU.According to Microsoft doc, ACU is currently standardized on a Small (Standard_A1) VM being 100 and all other SKUs then represent approximately how much faster that SKU can run a standard benchmark.

As p1v3 has minimal 195 ACU but 2 vCPU, does it mean we should expect minimal 390 ACU (195 *2)? So p2v2 will be faster but not much?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would interpret it as this:
The documentation says that for v3 this "ACU per vCPU", while for v2 it says "total ACU"

So in your case:

P2v2: 210 (per vCPU) x 2 = 420 total ACU
P1v3: 190 (per vCPU) x 2 = 380 total ACU (minimum - see below)

Since v3 contains hyper-threading while v2 does not, I guess the minimal of 190 in fact is to be interpreted as worst-case (when instead of 2 real cores only 1 real core with 2 threads is used).
I would guess that in most cases v3 will have more ACU and that this simply is just not guaranteed to be available at all times (therefore the minimum ACU).

Answer (score 0):

> azure app service plan difference between p2v2 and p1v3?

As per the [App Service Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/) document, it says:

***P1v3*** - Pay as you go -  `$0.33/hour`

- Premium v3 includes faster processors, Hyper-V virtualization, and VNet networking capability.
- The new Premium plan enables both containers and code-based deployments, with additional scale provided by enhanced vCPU, memory, and instance counts.
- **`Charge model`**:
  As with the v2 Plan, you now have access to one and three-year reservation price, **which lowers costs**. v3 Plans are now available in dev/test subscriptions as well.

***p2v2*** -  Pay as you go - `$0.40/hour`

- ***The Premium service plan is designed to give production apps better performance.***
- Premium v2, the enhanced Premium plan, includes Dv2-series VMs with faster CPUs, SSD storage, and a twice-as-large memory-to-core ratio than Standard.
- The new Premium plan also offers greater scale through increased instance count while maintaining all of the advanced features of the Standard plan.

You will save more money with reserved instances if you commit for a longer period of time.

***Reserved instances pricing for Pv3 on Linux and Windows allows you to run at a lower cost than identical Pv2 instances!***

Comment: but this doesn't explain what is minimal ACU?